# Close a circuit with one input signal

Tags: power, transistors

I have a circuit that can be broken down to this:
[image: Circuit to Close]

The [M54564P](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/M/5/4/5/M54564P_FP.shtml) has been stripped down to a single circuit from its 8 transistors to demonstrate it in a smaller scale.

The area of interest is where the *Resistor-LED* pairs are (which are just here to represent the load itself - values are not exact). The 5v signal comes from an Arduino and the 14v from a vehicle (car).

Lets say the 14v is always on while the 5v is switched by the Arduino.
When that happens, the M54564P will complete its circuit and output ~12v - this is where it gets complicated (for me).

I need to power on those two LEDs, preferably using the 14v signal - no relays (need to do this 6 times in total) - by using the 12v signal as activation.
While unpowered, they need to stay as demonstrated - I can't make their circuit parallel.

The *Output* (from the M54564P) can be used (there won't be a lot of draw from this), but I am trying to avoid this if possible - I would like to keep it as the activation signal - but the M54564P can provide the current I need with no issue (but maybe not the voltage for simultaneous output - I need at least two out of the 8 transistors active at any given time).

What do you guys/gals think?

Can I close this circuit by using the *Output* from the M54564P to feed the 14v to those two loads - without making them parallel while they are not powered on (they can be parallel while active of course)?

I am looking for transistors, diodes, ICs, etc - just not relays or devices that will draw too much current.

**Edit**:
To clarify on the outputs on the M54564P; I am already using 6 input and outputs from the M54564P (I need to control 6 independent circuits - a maximum of two circuits will be on at a time, no more) - each circuit has 2 loads that need to be switched on (that is what is represented by the Resistor-LED pair).

**Edit**:
While modifying my circuit on my drawing application, I might have stumbled across a way to solve my circuit.

Anyways, let me clarify a few things first:
The reason for the M54564P? It was recommended on an Arduino forum as a way to switch a positive signal on with the Arduino's 5v digital output.
As suggested by [Jasen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/13590/jasen) - I will look into the [A2982](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-power-distribution-switches-load-drivers/2556406?k=A2982) as a substitute. Thanks!

The load I am trying to drive is a Rostra's Dual Heated Seat control unit. It requires that a 12v signal be passed to the selected heat level and an additional (12v) signal that turns the heat unit itself on.

[image: Rostra Control Unit]

The part I am wiring into doesn't draw much at all and a Resistor-LED pair was the closest I could compare them to. I apologize for the confusion there.

Anyways, I spent a bit more time getting to know the control unit on the Rostra and came up with a way to power it up, send the 12v to the pin that selects the heat level while sending that same 12v signal onto the rest of the unit.

[image: Possible Solution?]

Does this look like a good solution or just a wasteful use of diodes?

I hope this does not cause further confusion - I only have my tiptoes in a bit into electrical engineering. I have a long way to go, but I have no plans to stop studying anything soon.

Comment: So in the photo, does switch connect two of the outer contacts in each position, and the outer contacts are in a non repeating order like 'A,B,C,D,E,A,C,E,B,D,A' (but with 6 letters instead of 5), and you want to mimic the switch operation.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I forgot to explain that part.
The control unit simply has a knob that bridges the contacts across with each other.
The contacts that are broken up the most is what selects the heat levels - the contacts closest to the bigger LEDs is the lowest level (goes up to ten).
For what I am doing, I only needed 3 levels (High, Medium and Low). There is a side you can't see on the picture (the one I am showing is the passenger side) so there are more contacts on the other side as well. Continued...

Comment: The reason why the last diagram above works is because I only need to bridge the two inner contacts (along with the contact that selects the heat level) only the circuit itself is active (which is the job of the Arduino).
There is a front panel on my dashboard that the Arduino is receiving button presses from, this is what determines the heat level. The Arduino counts the number of button presses and determines what heat level was picked and powers on the appropriate output pins.
Sorry that I am rambling on, but thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use 2 (as drawn) or 6 (as written) of the outputs of the 8 provided on the M54564P, **one for each LED**, that would be one way to have them not paralleled.

Another would be to add diodes between a single the M54564P output and each LED.

Faced with the updated problem

It looks like you have only a single extra output, need to drive a single extra dependant load.  I would thingk that driving that with a dedicated output would be preferable to using the diodes.

your drawing shouws 2 unused outputs on the driver chip and if you have a spare output on the arduino to drive the apropriate input pin just do that.

6 diodes to save one output pin seems like a lot of effort unless you haven't got a spare pin

Comment: I edited the question - I'm not able to make use of the M54564P to control _each_ load, since there are 6 separate circuits that I need to control, and each circuit has 2 loads.

Comment: @avluis, Can't you buy more M5464's as drivers?  one drive and one input (the 5 V signal) for each led.

Comment: Buying more is not a problem (but they are hard to find sometimes - too many fakes), but I am not driving LEDs...
I will replace the circuit with the full diagram once I draw it all to stop the confusion.
The Resistor-LED pairs was to show a _load_ only.
I think I will go ahead and replicate all of the transistors in the M54564P as well.

Comment: hard to get? Maybe buy them from a reputable vendor then! Digikey has nearly 50 thousand A2982 in stock, if not resistor and LED please indicate power requirements of the load.

Comment: Thanks for that part number - I can look into using this one instead of the M54564P.
As for power requirements, almost nothing, I measured and average of 3.4mA to 4.5mA to drive this load.
I will be editing the question with a bit more detail about the load itself as well, just need to get to grips with the software I am using.

Comment: I see what you are suggesting and I can definitely implement that since I am also turning on pin 13 (the onboard LED) on the Arduino if any of those outputs is on.
I can definitely see the proper way to wire this now - drive the additional signal with logic from the Arduino itself (it makes too much sense now!) - if any of the pins are active, then the additional signal is active as well~
Thanks for sticking along and helping me figure this out.

I'll be back with an updated wiring diagram for those that stumble upon a similar problem in the future.